# i am getting an error at line 39:30 no viable alternative at character ' '

Tags: apex

```
public class HighChart4 {

    private String x,y;   

    public HighChart4(){

        List<AggregateResult> quarter1=[select Account.name,sum(amount) from Opportunity where StageName='Closed Won' and CloseDate > 2016-01-01 and CloseDate < 2016-04-01 and Account.name like 'Ozil%' group by Account.name];

        List<AggregateResult> quarter2=[select Account.name,sum(amount) from Opportunity where StageName='Prospecting' and CloseDate > 2016-04-01 and CloseDate < 2016-07-01 and Account.name like 'Stanley%' group by Account.name];

        List<AggregateResult> quarter3=[select Account.name,sum(amount) from Opportunity where StageName='Closed Lost' and CloseDate > 2016-07-01 and CloseDate < 2016-10-01 and Account.name like 'Rooney%' group by Account.name];

        List<AggregateResult> quarter4=[select Account.name,sum(amount) from Opportunity where StageName='Qualification' and CloseDate > 2016-10-01 and CloseDate < 2017-01-01 and Account.name like 'Morgan%' group by Account.name];  


        List<CurrencyType> yval = new List<CurrencyType>();


        for(AggregateResult q1:quarter1)
        {       
            yval.add(q1.get('expr0'));
            //System.debug(q1.Account.name); 
        }
        for(AggregateResult q2:quarter2)
        {           
            yval.add(q2.get('expr0'));
            //System.debug(q2.Account.name); 
        }
        for(AggregateResult q3:quarter3)
        {       
            yval.add(q3.get('expr0'));
            //System.debug(q3.Account.name);
        }     
        for(AggregateResult q4:quarter4)
        {       
           yval.add(q4.get('expr0'));
            //System.debug(q4.Account.name);
        }       
       y=JSON.serialize(yval);       
    }  

public String gety() {
        return y;

}
}
```

Comment: Which line is 39?

Comment: It looks like the line is `y=JSON.serialize(yval);`

Comment: Is CurrencyType a wrapper class? If so, can you post its definition?

Comment: fortunately i was able to solve it...Instead of using CurrencyType i used decimal and also in my for loop i forced decimal convert.Worked fine..But thanx for ur help..!!

Comment: List<decimal> yval = new List<decimal>();

Comment: I used this and error was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the JSON parser is unable to understand the conversion of **CurrencyType** to appropriate JSON compatible datatype.

**Ref:**

- For the list of compatible JSON datatypes refer here: http://www.json.org/

Since the result set in SUM(Amount) is an Integer and JSON will not understand any difference between Integer and CurrecyType will this change work better for you ?

```
    List<Integer> yval = new List<Integer>();
    yval.add((Integer)q.get('expr0'));
```